# ExecuteSqlInterpolated/ExecuteSqlRaw parameters pass to database incorrectly in asp.net core

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core

I am attempting to use ExecuteSqlInterpolated to update my database. However, it seems that there is a problem with my SQL parameters. Running the following code correctly updates intField1 and intField2, however stringField becomes the string "@p0".

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"UPDATE table SET stringField='{someString}', intField1={someInt}, intField2={someOtherInt} WHERE id='{id}'");
```

I have already verified that my variables contain the desired values when the string is passed to the method. I understand that @p0 is what SQL uses to represent the first parameter in the query, but why isn't it being replaced by the string I gave it? I have also tried using ExecuteSqlRaw but ran into the same issue. My knowledge of SQL is limited at best, I know just enough to get by in web dev, so I'm guessing I'm committing some simple error in crafting the query here, but obviously I'm not sure.

Comment: They should all be `@p<something>`. `ExecuteSqlInterpolated` does not expand the variables, it creates parameters for them. If it did that would be a sql injection vulnerability and no advantage over just executing raw sql.

Comment: you don’t need to quote something, quoting it is your problem

Comment: Thank you jmoreno, you were absolutely correct. Also, out of curiosity, anybody out there know why one would use the interpolated method over the raw method and vice versa?

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late but just don't use quotation mark with your parameters, specially where you use int data-type
(delete single quotes)

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated($"UPDATE table SET stringField={someString}, intField1={someInt}, intField2={someOtherInt} WHERE id={id}");
```